# newtonsoft Serialize XML attributes issues

Tags: c#, xml, json.net

I am Serializing XML document with the help of `json.net`..

Some of the XML elements have attributes, so when i use:

`JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(xml, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);`

The XML element `<shipmentIndex Name="items">0</shipmentIndex>`

transform to that JSON:
`{"shipmentIndex":{"@Name":"items","#text":"0"}`

I am sending this JSON to an API that expect something like that:
`{"shipmentIndex":0}`

How can i send to the API the correct data?

- i used the attributes for formatting the JSON according to the API demands.

Answer (score 4):

If your `xml` variable is of type [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement), you can try to use it's [`RemoveAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.removeattributes) method:

```
var cleanXML = xml;
cleanXML.RemoveAttributes();
JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(cleanXML, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
```

Comment: Yes i am using `XElement` but the code you suggested cause an error `The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(System.Xml.Linq.XObject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting, bool)' has some invalid arguments` , ` cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Xml.Linq.XObject' `

Comment: I didn't try it myself but according to the documentation of the `RemoveAttributes` this should not happen. Are you sure you changed the code to match my edit?

Comment: `public void RemoveAttributes`, SerializeXNode expect XObject as the first parameter